# Making properties observable in array with Knockout.js Mapping Plugin

Tags: mapping, knockout.js

When I call `ko.mapping.fromJS(model)` it creates a blank array.  I am trying to create an observable array with observable properties.  The initial model variable object as a string looks like this `"[{"Key":"test","Speeches":[{"Text":"test"}]}]"`.  Why is the fromJS method returning an empty array `[]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is in JSON (string representation), then you need to use `ko.mapping.fromJSON(model)`.

Otherwise, it should work fine.  I know that console.log on an observableArray in Chrome shows [], so maybe the data is there.

Here is a sample that shows both ways and that the data is valid: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PBhG3/

Comment: You maybe right then. We went a different route at the moment but I will mark it as correct.